# AT90USB1286 as a potential storage device for a few kilobytes of data

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmel

I have a few trays of [AT90USB1286](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/AT90USB1286) microcontrollers leftover from a previous project that I would like to make use of.

Is it possible to make this chip act as a block device when connected to a PC? I would only require a few kilobytes of storage (under 100 KB). Is there perhaps a way to use the internal EPROM for this?

I assume at the very least I will need some basic filesystem like FAT16 for the PC to be able to read from the device. Writing/modifying from the PC is not required, read-only is fine. Writing to the device from the MCU is also required.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you are comfortable using a USB stack and that there is one you can just use freely, then you just focus on providing all the right responses to the PC and its O/S when the device is plugged in. An appropriate driver should already exist in the O/S, so why not try?

Comment: @periblepsis Commonly such a microcontroller does not run an operating system, but is programmed bare-metal. However, there are frameworks that provide some kind of operating system.

Comment: The internal EEPROM is not big enough to hold that much, IIRC. Anyway, grab the USB documentation for mass storage and implement the necessary parts. -- You can even consider to put a compressed image of the file system in the flash or EEPROM or an external device and decompress it on-the-fly. -- Speaking of file systems, you need to decide which one you will use, since you say that it shall be read-only. Otherwise you could just implement the necessary minimum and let the PC format the "drive".